# Google Chart Setting Gridline Color

Tags: javascript, syntax, google-visualization, gridlines

I'm trying to set the color of the gridlines in the background of my Graph using Google Charts.

I've got this code for setting the options of the chart:

```
ac.draw(activityData, {
    title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    isStacked: true,
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    fontSize: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#1E4D6B',
        hAxis.gridlines.color: '#1E4D6B'
});
```

However, I don't know how to use the options like `hAxis.gridlines.color` within my code that appear in the [configuration options page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options).

If I simply put `hAxis.gridlines.color`, it comes up with an error in the console of:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

What is the correct syntax to make use of the options that contain periods?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's an object litteral you're passing as second parameter of *draw()*, so I guess it should instead be :

`hAxis: {gridlines: {color: '#1E4D6B'}}`

Answer (score 6):

`gridlineColor: '#f0f'` also works, and this is how you do it.

```
{vAxis: {gridlineColor: '#f0f'}}
```